# How can I access data on a computer without knowing the login password?

Tags: login, data-recovery, password-recovery

There are a number of files (photos, stories, poetry... etc.) on a computer that I need to retrieve. Is there any way to get around the login procedure or to get to my files without the password? Any help would be appreciated and please break down any complicated directions as I haven't used a linux system for a few years.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/44179

Comment: Resetting the password (as in the proposed dupe target), booting up, and logging on is just one of several reasonable ways to access files in a system on which one does not have a password. I don't think we should close this as a duplicate of that, as there are a variety of other ways, some which are often preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If the partitions and folders aren't encrypted, you might try to

1. boot to a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
2. `chown` the files in question to `nobody:root` or the USB's user - or even `root:root` - anything that makes it possible for you to move them
3. Pull up `gksu nautilus`, copy the files to another backup drive.

Other than that - if you know the current version installed on that PC, you might even try to install a [more recent version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and chose the *upgrade* option (should be available, haven't checked with the recent versions).

Comment: Well option one is a no go. At least not right this minute. And as for installing an upgrade, how exactly do I go about this? And can I get a physical copy of ubuntu?

Comment: @Brandon In both cases you would be required to create a bootable medium - DVD or Stick - and boot to Ubuntu, either to install it, or to simply run it. As for upgrading - as I said, I'm not sure how it works now. As far as I remember there is an option on the screen at the 4th step of [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) that allows upgrading.

Comment: @Brandon You might want to check if the question iSeth linked to works for you, however. I personally had issues with that once, though - hence why I'm not using it myself. :D